# Compare pairs of proportions for three groups

Tags: multiple-comparisons, proportion

I have a interesting problem, where patients are categorized in three groups, namely `Severe`, `Moderate`, and `Mild` and they are measured over two time slices. Each particular cell represents proportion of patients with each category.

```
            | Severe | Moderate | Mild |
------------+--------+----------+------|
Timepoint 1 |   18.8 |      4.3 |  9.7 |
------------+--------+----------+------|
Timepoint 2 |   23.8 |      4.5 |  4.3 |
```

Now I want to draw a conclusion if the proportions in `Timepoint 1` are significantly different from proportions in `Timepoint 2`.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/205712/chi-squared-for-multiple-samples & https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/158654/possibility-to-run-multiple-chi-square-tests-on-2x5-table

Comment: A  nice and ticklish question. I think you may try  chi square test.